# FlatList - How to detect when refresh is finished?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I need to do some actions when the user has finished refreshing the data on my FlatList with onRefresh props.

I didn't find anything on the doc, so I was wondering if there was any way to do something like that?

Comment: what is mean refreshing the data? scrolling to end? coming new data to the list?

Comment: When user refreshing FlatList with onRefresh props (pull to refresh), I need to refresh my redux store and after that, call my API to get new informations.
So I am looking for a solution so that when my onRefresh is finished, I can execute a function. Like an onRefreshOver or something like that.
I'm not sure it's clear

Comment: Do you mean blocking the pull refresh when there is no new data from now on?

Comment: Ok i get you, please share your code

Comment: [this is my code](https://pastebin.com/BzEkHj7W) @idan so I want to reset my store redux list during the onRefresh and when onRefresh is over, I want to fetch my new data. 
I heard about thunk redux but I'm completely lost with that, so this is the reason why I'm looking for an alternative solution like 'onRefreshOver'

Comment: I don't know if there is something like that because the list loading lazy so when it starts to show items it's not the time that list end to loading, maybe try to do something with `onEndReached` property

Comment: Oh yes, you right! It seems completely logical!
I'll check with onEndReached! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this
https://medium.com/@pateldhara248/flatlist-with-loadmore-and-pull-to-refresh-582d48eca60b.
It says that you need to provide refreshControl prop to FlatList which will be your Component displayed when the flatList is pulled to refresh. and to this component you will provide prop onRefresh which will be a function called when the Flatlist is pulled to refresh so in that function you can call your API to fetch data for the FlatList.